# How to properly write time-dependent operator $\phi(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, notation, operator-theory, definition

For a simple ODE: $u' = u, \: \: \: t \ge 0$, with initial condition $u(0)=1$, the exact solution is
$$u(t) = e^{t}$$

Now if the initial condition $u(0) = u_{0}$ then the exact solution is written
$$u(t) = u_{0}e^{t}$$

Now define $\phi(t; u_{0})$ as the exact solution of the ODE above with initial condition $u_{0}$. For example:
$$\phi(t; 1) = e^{t}$$
$$\phi(t; -5.9) = -5.9e^{t}$$
$$\phi(t; 0.11) = 0.11e^{t}$$

This definition is useful as follows:
$$\phi(0.5; \phi(0.5; 0.11)) = \phi(1; 0.11)  $$

but cumbersome to read.

So instead of defining $\phi$ as a function with parameter of initial condition, how can I properly/rigourously define $\phi$ as a time-dependent operator such that

$$ \phi(t)(u_{0}) = u_{0}e^{t}$$
so that I can neatly write, for example

$$ \phi^{2}(0.1) u_{0} = \phi(0.1)\phi(0.1)u_{0} = \phi(0.2) u_{0} $$

Comment: I don't think there's a standard notation for that, but you can usually setup your own notation at the start and use it consistently throughout, e.g. $f_\lambda(x)=x^2+\lambda$ is useful for analyzing dynamical systems.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite standard to write $\phi_t(x_0)$ for $\phi(t;x_0)$, sometimes also in the superscript position. Then the (semi-)group property for the flow of autonomous DE can be conveniently written as $$\phi_t\circ\phi_s=\phi_{t+s}.$$

In the superscript variant one would get the suggestive $(\phi^t)^{\circ n}=\phi^{nt}$.

Comment: Any alternative than $\phi_{t}(x_{0})$? since it looks like partial derivative and I am going to extend this into PDE also.

Comment: There are only so many symbols and ways to compose them. You could write the derivatives as operators $D_t\phi$ or $\partial_t\phi$. Or employ an older convention that is closer connected to tensor calculus and separate the function arguments from the derivative place indicators with a comma or semi-colon, $\phi_{t;t}$. Your way of writing $\phi(t)(x_0)$ is also valid, if uncommon. More common is the combination of different forms of parentheses, like $\phi(t)[x_0]$ (which is commonly used for a linear operator $\phi(t)$) or ${\cal F}\{f\}(\omega)$ as notation of the Fourier transform.